# Xcode Class name in iOS without application name prefix

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xib

I'm trying to load `UIView` from xib with this code

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
_customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

In another project it works fine, but in my new project className returns `"myapp.MyClassName"`. I don't know why it adds application name "myapp." prefix before class name. I don't have nib named `"myapp.MyClassName.xib"` so application crashes with

```
Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/XXXX-XXXX/myapp.app> (loaded)' with name 'myapp.MyClassName''
```

I have:

- CustomXibUIView class (Objective C) that initialize _customView
- MyClassName class (Swift) that inherits CustomXibUIView (for initializer)
- MyClassName.xib

I'm using XCode6-Beta5, `iOS SDK 8.0`, deployment target iOS7+

How can I get clear class name without prefix?

Comment: I have the same problem. It only appears to happen for Swift files. Quite ugly having to split on '.'.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
class var getClassFullName: String { return NSStringFromClass(self)   }

class var getClassName: String {
  return (getClassFullName as NSString).pathExtension
}
```